# How can I parse the binary and ascii combination file

Tags: java, file, utf-8, binary, hex

I have files that have both ASCII text and binary contents

When I parsing that files to UTF-8 encoding type

ASCII type parts are readable, but Binary coded parts can't read..

and entire length is correct. therefore that file's encoding type is UTF-8.

but how can I parse Binary coded parts by java program?

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all...
If it is binary why do you want to read it ? you just can't if it's a binary file (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file)
I don't think it's an utf8 problem. But maybe I'm wrong tell us more about what you already did and what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read 1 byte and decide:
 - it is ASCII or maybe UTF-8 ( if greather than 127, than maybe UTF-8)
 - if is ASCII than add to String and state reset.

if maybe UTF-8:
read the second part: next byte.
If the last 2 bytes are UTF-8 than add to String and state reset
If not an acceptable UTF-8 char, than the last 2 was a binary data: add to data queue.

Process next bytes until end of file.

In this case you will have all possible ASCII and all Possible UTF-8 characters and the remains dor Data.

Can be the case when the readed characters was in data, there are no way to know until you have the original file descriptior. Something like:
at position 1000 start a data block until.... pos 2000.
at position 2000 start until 2500 ASCII String
 and so on.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Depends.

Read the file as binary, maybe as a ByteBuffer, so byte sequences might be picked up as strings.

Alternatively, if you could make a grammar of the format, that would be feasible too: matching keywords on byte level with `String.getBytes("UTF-8")`. [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) if you really want to put effort in a gramamr solution.

Comment: what? oh that is goood idea!

Comment: I don't have any idea to that!!

Comment: file's type is UTF-8 and one data's length are 1024 bytes

Comment: and I parsed that file only to ASCII type file!! another option is